# How to make a [tab] in Chrome Console?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to make a `tab` in Chrome Console? Now I have click `space` two of four times to make an indent. Is there a `tab` key?

```
class A {
    constructor(val) {   // <- tab
        this.a = val;    // <- 2x tab
    } // <- tab
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently available. Tab is used for autocompletion.

You can file a feature request on the [Chromium issue tracker](https://crbug.com) to see if it could get implemented.